# iOS: Realm + Layar SDK = Assertion failed: typeid(Col) == typeid(col)

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, realm, layar

I have been trying to integrate a new SDK (from [Layar](https://www.layar.com/documentation/layar-sdk/tutorial-integrate-iphone-sdk/)) in my app that already contains the Realm SDK.

The app was working fine up until now (with Realm). As soon as I add the Layar SDK following the steps in the link above (I don't actually call any functionality, I just add the framework and dependencies), the app crashes on launch at the Realm config, with the trace below.

Any ideas as to what might be causing the behaviour?

```
../realm/table.hpp:1470: [realm-core-0.92.4] Assertion failed: typeid(Col) == typeid(col)
0   XXContainerIOSDebug            0x00000001004747ec _ZN5realm4util18terminate_internalERNSt3__118basic_stringstreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE + 44
1   XXContainerIOSDebug            0x000000010030b83c _ZN5realm4util9terminateEPKcS2_l + 1196
2   XXContainerIOSDebug            0x0000000100535f08 _ZNK5realm5Table8get_boolEmm + 0
3   XXContainerIOSDebug            0x00000001003b86b8 _ZN5realm11ObjectStore22create_metadata_tablesEPNS_5GroupE + 588
4   XXContainerIOSDebug            0x00000001003bed0c _ZN5realm11ObjectStore24update_realm_with_schemaEPNS_5GroupEyRNSt3__16vectorINS_12ObjectSchemaENS3_9allocatorIS5_EEEENS3_8functionIFvS2_S9_EEE + 72
5   XXContainerIOSDebug            0x0000000100321188 RLMUpdateRealmToSchemaVersion + 1512
6   XXContainerIOSDebug            0x000000010038cd6c +[RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:error:] + 4148
7   XXContainerIOSDebug            0x000000010038b490 +[RLMRealm defaultRealm] + 92
8   XXContainerIOSDebug            0x000000010019c294 -[XXNewsstand init] + 708
9   XXContainerIOSDebug            0x000000010019b92c __34+[XXNewsstand sharedInstance]_block_invoke + 60
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001013c9bb0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001013caa28 dispatch_once_f + 132
12  XXContainerIOSDebug            0x000000010019b8d0 +[XXNewsstand sharedInstance] + 144
13  XXContainerIOSDebug            0x00000001001b09f4 -[XXTrackingManager init] + 272
14  XXContainerIOSDebug            0x00000001001b089c __36+[XXTrackingManager sharedInstance]_block_invoke + 60
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001013c9bb0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001013caa28 dispatch_once_f + 132
17  XXContainerIOSDebug            0x00000001001b0840 +[XXTrackingManager sharedInstance] + 144
18  XXContainerIOSDebug            0x000000010003d338 -[XXAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1212
19  UIKit                               0x00000001880a1704 <redacted> + 400
20  UIKit                               0x00000001882d0130 <redacted> + 2904
21  UIKit                               0x00000001882d44b8 <redacted> + 1672
22  UIKit                               0x00000001882d15c0 <redacted> + 168
23  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001848ef790 <redacted> + 184
24  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001848efb10 <redacted> + 56
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001832f0efc <redacted> + 24
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001832f0990 <redacted> + 540
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001832ee690 <redacted> + 724
28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018321d680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
29  UIKit                               0x000000018809a580 <redacted> + 460
30  UIKit                               0x0000000188094d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
31  XXContainerIOSDebug            0x00000001000348a8 main + 124
32  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000182dbe8b8 <redacted> + 4
IMPORTANT: if you see this error, please send this log to help@realm.io.
```

Comment: What version of Realm are you running? The fact the log is reporting 'realm-core-0.92.4' seems to suggest it's a relatively older version (We're at v0.95 now). Additionally, does this crash happen reliably, even if you delete the app and install it again?

Comment: The Podfile says `Realm (0.95.3):` but the `version.hpp` says 0.92.4. Is that the real version? I'll try to update it.

Comment: Yeah, `version.hpp` is referring to the internal engine of Realm, which is on a separate version track to the Cocoa binding. Cool! Let me know how you go!

Comment: I overhauled the app and moved to using cocoapods and the issue is now fixed even if I use this older version of Realm. I understand that the cause was probably some modification of libraries by previous developers or something.